# C# Method Overload vs. Interface Parameter

Tags: c#, interface, overloading

I'm just curious, what is considered the "best practice" for the following example: I have either a numeric array or numeric list and want to supply it to a function to return the average.

Is it better to overload the method for each case:

```
double Average(int[] intArray){...}
double Average(uint[] uintArray){...}
double Average(double[] doubleArray){...}
...
double Average(List<int> intList){...}
...
```

Or, is it better to use some type of interface:

```
double Average(IEnumerable arrayOrList)
{
   // Branching logic for array or list.
}
```

Thanks!

**EDIT**

`Average` is used as an example. I have several numeric algorithms which need to be able to run on a variety of numeric data.

Comment: This looks like a prime candidate for an extension method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the various overloads of the [Enumerable.Average Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.average.aspx) for guidance:

```
public static double Average(this IEnumerable<int> source)
```

A method in this style works for any collection type that implements [IEnumerable<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) ([T[]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx), [List<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx), [HashSet<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx), [ReadOnlyCollection<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx), ...) and avoids the overhead incurred by a non-generic [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) argument. Since C# doesn't have a `where T : num` [constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx), you need to provide an overload for all primitive types you wish to support ([Int32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx), [Int64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int64.aspx), [Single](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.aspx), [Double](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx), [Decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx), ...).

Comment: I should have mentioned that I just used average as an example. I have several numeric algorithms which need to act on collections of data.

Answer (score 1):

An interface will allow you to supply an array or any other collection. You might want to use a strongly typed interface like `IEnumerable<int>` though.

Comment: I assume that by "a strongly typed interface like IEnumerable" you mean "a strongly typed interface like IEnumerable<T>"?

Comment: I just edited my answer, hadn't put it in a code block so the angle brackets didn't show

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Average` is just an example, you should use IEnumerable but overload the funciton with your data type, like so: `IEnumerable<DataType>`

For example:

```
double Average(IEnumerable<Int32> array){...}
double Average(IEnumerable<Double> array){...}
```